# TYPO3 pibase extension with compatibility6 - Duplicate double main() method calls

Tags: typo3, pibase

We're trying to use a legacy pibase extension that worked in a TYPO3 6.1 installation in a TYPO3 7.6 environment. We installed the compatibility6 extension.

The pibase extension basically works, but something (TM) seems to call the pibase main() method twice; this confuses a bit of the internal workings of the extension, because static counters do not start fresh.

We found out that tt_news has the same problem, it is executed twice and thus can lose pagination properties.

Might this be an issue of the compatibility6 extension, or within the TYPO3v7 core? We couldn't easily deduce where exactly the first call happens (the output is actually created in the second main() call).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually that in typoscript we added multiple calls to get the content:

```
page.10.variables {
   main_content < styles.content.get
   main_content.select.where = colPos = 0

   another_content < styles.content.get
   another_content.select.where = colPos = 0
}
```

We needed to rewrite this to specifically only get the main content once. Maybe this helps someone with a similar problem.